# HTML5 Canvas get transform matrix?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to get the current transformation matrix for a canvas? There is a context.setTransform() function, but there does not seem to be a getTransform() equivalent as far as I can tell.

More specifically, I want to get the current scale and translation elements of the matrix. Google has been very unhelpful with this.

Answer (score 30):

No, there simply isn't. :(

Most canavs libraries (such as cake.js) have instead implemented their own matrix class to keep track of the current transformation matrix.

The creator of cake.js thought that there being no way to get the current matrix was ridiculous enough to warrant a [bug report about it.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=408804) Unfortunately that was back in 2007 and there has been no effort to include a getCurrentTransform in the spec.

**Edit:** I have created a simple Transformation class that will allow you to easily make your own `getCanvas()` or keep track of the Canvas's matrix side-by-side. [Here it is.](https://simonsarris.com/a-transformation-class-for-canvas-to-keep-track-of-the-transformation-matrix/) I hope that helps!

**Edit June 2012:** The new specification does include a way to get the current transformation matrix! `context.currentTransform` can be used to get or set the current transformation matrix. Unfortunately no browsers have implemented it yet, though Firefox does have the vendor-specific `mozCurrentTransform` property on its context. So you can't use it just yet, but it is in the spec, so soon!

Comment: There's also [a message from David Flanagan](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2010Jul/0458.html) to W3 on the lack of this dated 28 Jul 2010

Comment: Instead of implementing your own class, you might be able to use the [SVGMatrix object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGMatrix).

Comment: Indeed, @DaveKennedy, that works (in Chrome at least). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936587/how-to-create-an-svg-matrix-without-an-svg-element-in-the-dom).

Answer (score 18):

EDIT(1/10/2020): [MDN now indicates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getTransform#Browser_compatibility) that `getTransform()` is supported in most major browsers; the code below may still have value as a part of implementing a polyfill for Internet Explorer, Edge, and Android Firefox.

EDIT(6/27/2016): The WHATWG spec now has a function [`getTransform()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-gettransform) instead of `currentTransform` and it appears semantically clear that `getTransform()` creates a *copy* of the transformation matrix.  Looks like it is still missing from major browsers.

EDIT, again:

Here's a rough implementation:

```
//in theory, SVGMatrix will be used by the Canvas API in the future;
//in practice, we can borrow an SVG matrix today!
var createMatrix = function() {
  var svgNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  return document.createElementNS(svgNamespace, "g").getCTM();
}

//`enhanceContext` takes a 2d canvas context and wraps its matrix-changing
//functions so that `context._matrix` should always correspond to its
//current transformation matrix.
//Call `enhanceContext` on a freshly-fetched 2d canvas context for best
//results.
var enhanceContext = function(context) {
  var m = createMatrix();
  context._matrix = m;

  //the stack of saved matrices
  context._savedMatrices = [m];

  var super_ = context.__proto__;
  context.__proto__ = ({

    //helper for manually forcing the canvas transformation matrix to
    //match the stored matrix.
    _setMatrix: function() {
      var m = this._matrix;
      super_.setTransform.call(this, m.a, m.b, m.c, m.d, m.e, m.f);
    },

    save: function() {
      this._savedMatrices.push(this._matrix);
      super_.save.call(this);
    },

    //if the stack of matrices we're managing doesn't have a saved matrix,
    //we won't even call the context's original `restore` method.
    restore: function() {
      if(this._savedMatrices.length == 0)
        return;
      super_.restore.call(this);
      this._matrix = this._savedMatrices.pop();
      this._setMatrix();
    },

    scale: function(x, y) {
      this._matrix = this._matrix.scaleNonUniform(x, y);
      super_.scale.call(this, x, y);
    },

    rotate: function(theta) {
      //canvas `rotate` uses radians, SVGMatrix uses degrees.
      this._matrix = this._matrix.rotate(theta * 180 / Math.PI);
      super_.rotate.call(this, theta);
    },

    translate: function(x, y) {
      this._matrix = this._matrix.translate(x, y);
      super_.translate.call(this, x, y);
    },

    transform: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
      var rhs = createMatrix();
      //2x2 scale-skew matrix
      rhs.a = a; rhs.b = b;
      rhs.c = c; rhs.d = d;

      //translation vector
      rhs.e = e; rhs.f = f;
      this._matrix = this._matrix.multiply(rhs);
      super_.transform.call(this, a, b, c, d, e, f);
    },

    //warning: `resetTransform` is not implemented in at least some browsers
    //and this is _not_ a shim.
    resetTransform: function() {
      this._matrix = createMatrix();
      super_.resetTransform.call(this);
    },

    __proto__: super_
  });

  return context;  
};
```

EDIT:
The attribute `currentTransform` [has been added to the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-currenttransform); it is reported to be supported in Firefox and Opera.  I checked on Firefox and found it vendor-prefixed as `mozCurrentTransform`.  Presumably it can be used to both get and set the transform matrix.

OLDER STUFF, STILL MOSTLY TRUE:

If you want to get the current transformation matrix, you'll have to keep track of it yourself.  One way of doing this would be to use Javascript's prototypical inheritance to add a `getMatrix()` method and augment the methods which modify the matrix:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var super = context.__proto__;
context.__proto__ = ({

  __proto__: super, //"inherit" default behavior

  getMatrix: function() { return this.matrix; },

  scale: function(x, y) {

    //assuming the matrix manipulations are already defined...
    var newMatrix = scaleMatrix(x, y, this.getMatrix());
    this.matrix = newMatrix;
    return super.scale.call(this, x, y);
  },
  /* similar things for rotate, translate, transform, setTransform */
  /* ... */
});
context.matrix = makeDefaultMatrix();
```

To really get it right, you'd need to track multiple matrices when the `save()` and `restore()` methods of the context are used.

Comment: @Ben Dilts or ellisbben: can any of you guys please put the complete solution somewhere?

Comment: @kikito What I just added should be reasonably complete.  I only tested `transform`, `rotate`, `translate`, `save`, and `restore` superficially.

Comment: @kikito If you're willing to write a test or two, I'll write a test or two and we can make a tiny github project out of it :)

Comment: @ellisbben I just found this: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/a_bicky/20120724/1343084686 Maybe it'll be good enough?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good; that style of messing with the prototype is clearer, I guess.  I still think borrowing SVGMatrix rather than implementing one's own is a good move.

Comment: Now in 2023, I think the correct solution is to force users to upgrade their browsers since most major browsers implemented this 4+ years ago.

Answer (score 2):

As @ellisbben mentioned pretty much the only way you can do this is to keep track of it yourself. You can find one solution [here](http://proceduralgraphics.blogspot.com/2010/03/canvas-wrapper-with-gettransform.html). It wraps the context within a wrapper and then handles the nasty bits there.

Answer (score 0):

Motivated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48536014/3624264), I updated @ellisbben's answer to use a Proxy instead of prototype inheritance (which didn't work for me). The code [linked in the comments of @ellisbben's answer](https://abicky.net/2012/07/24/080446/) overriding `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype` also didn't work. ([See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840757/3624264).)

```js
// in theory, SVGMatrix will be used by the Canvas API in the future;
// in practice, we can borrow an SVG matrix today!
function createMatrix() {
  const svgNamespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  return document.createElementNS(svgNamespace, 'g').getCTM();
}

// `enhanceContext` takes a 2d canvas context and wraps its matrix-changing
// functions so that `context.currentTransform` should always correspond to its
// current transformation matrix.
// Call `enhanceContext` on a freshly-fetched 2d canvas context for best
// results.
function enhanceContext(context) {
  // The main property we are enhancing the context to track
  let currentTransform = createMatrix();

  // the stack of saved matrices
  const savedTransforms = [currentTransform];

  const enhanced = {
    currentTransform,
    savedTransforms,
    // helper for manually forcing the canvas transformation matrix to
    // match the stored matrix.
    _setMatrix() {
      const m = enhanced.currentTransform;
      context.setTransform(m.a, m.b, m.c, m.d, m.e, m.f);
    },

    save() {
      enhanced.savedTransforms.push(enhanced.currentTransform);
      context.save();
    },

    // if the stack of matrices we're managing doesn't have a saved matrix,
    // we won't even call the context's original `restore` method.
    restore() {
      if (enhanced.savedTransforms.length == 0) return;
      context.restore();
      enhanced.currentTransform = enhanced.savedTransforms.pop();
      enhanced._setMatrix();
    },

    scale(x, y) {
      enhanced.currentTransform = enhanced.currentTransform.scaleNonUniform(
        x,
        y
      );
      context.scale(x, y);
    },

    rotate(theta) {
      // canvas `rotate` uses radians, SVGMatrix uses degrees.
      enhanced.currentTransform = enhanced.currentTransform.rotate(
        (theta * 180) / Math.PI
      );
      context.rotate(theta);
    },

    translate(x, y) {
      enhanced.currentTransform = enhanced.currentTransform.translate(x, y);
      context.translate(x, y);
    },

    transform(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
      const rhs = createMatrix();
      // 2x2 scale-skew matrix
      rhs.a = a;
      rhs.b = b;
      rhs.c = c;
      rhs.d = d;

      // translation vector
      rhs.e = e;
      rhs.f = f;
      enhanced.currentTransform = enhanced.currentTransform.multiply(rhs);
      context.transform(a, b, c, d, e, f);
    },

    // Warning: `resetTransform` is not implemented in at least some browsers
    // and this is _not_ a shim.
    resetTransform() {
      enhanced.currentTransform = createMatrix();
      context.resetTransform();
    },
  };

  const handler = {
    get: (target, key) => {
      const value =
        key in enhanced
          ? enhanced[key]
          : key in target
          ? target[key]
          : undefined;
      if (value === undefined) {
        return value;
      }
      return typeof value === 'function'
        ? (...args) => value.apply(target, args)
        : value;
    },
    set: (target, key, value) => {
      if (key in target) {
        target[key] = value;
      }
      return value;
    },
  };

  return new Proxy(context, handler);
}

function testIt() {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const enhanced = enhanceContext(ctx);
  const log = (msg) => {
    const { a, b, c, d, e, f } = enhanced.currentTransform;
    console.log(msg, { a, b, c, d, e, f });
  };
  window.enhanced = enhanced;
  log('initial');

  enhanced.save();
  enhanced.scale(1, 2);
  log('scale(1,2)');
  enhanced.restore();

  enhanced.save();
  enhanced.translate(10, 20);
  log('translate(10,20)');
  enhanced.restore();

  enhanced.save();
  enhanced.rotate(30);
  log('rotate(30)');
  enhanced.restore();

  enhanced.save();
  enhanced.scale(1, 2);
  enhanced.translate(10, 20);
  log('scale(1,2) translate(10,20)');
  enhanced.restore();
}

testIt();
```