# Draw a line from x,y with a given angle and length

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In Javascript I want to draw a line from x/y with a given length and angle. I don't want to draw a line from x1/y1 to x2/y2. I have an x/y origin, an angle and a length.

The line needs to sit on top of a standard web page at a specific position.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Believe me, you do want to draw a line to x2/y2. Just think how you might compute these coordinates you don't know.

Comment: Well, you're basically saying you want to draw a line using polar coordinates instead of rectilinear ones. You can just convert your points using trig. Basic high school math: if you have a vector of length `r` and an angle `θ`, you can write this vector as r(cosθ + sinθ) = rcosθ + rsinθ. This gives you the length of `x` and `y`, meaning you can then easily draw the line on a canvas.

Comment: What commands for drawing a line do you have available to you?

Comment: I can use anything that will get the job done. Probably canvas if it sits nicely on top of html without swallowing events intended for the background html

Comment: `x2 = x1 + r*cos(theta); y2 = y1 + r*sin(theta);`

Comment: Is there a simple js lib that will take my values and draw a line?

Comment: Looks good Floris thanks I'll use your code as a basis. I've seen lots of libs that can draw point to point.

Comment: Thanks Luxelin, I'm looking at d3 now

Comment: @Newt-7 I'll make you a basic example; hold up.

Comment: @CBroe can you pinpoint those basic maths? It would be better to comment which basic maths you are talking about.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - I believe that my earlier comment shows what that basic maths (trigonometry) is...

Comment: @Floris  That does, but CBroe's comment does not. Thanks for pinpointing this out for the guy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047378/finding-coordinates-after-canvas-rotation/17053883#17053883

Comment: @epistemex - that is a very good answer/link!

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of the one listed

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`moveTo(x,y)` defines the starting point of the line
`lineTo(x,y)` defines the ending point of the line

So you want something like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
x1 = 30;
y1 = 40;
r =  50;
theta = 0.5;
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
ctx.lineTo(x1 + r * Math.cos(theta), y1 + r * Math.sin(theta));
ctx.stroke();
```

where you must make sure that `theta` is in radians and that `ctx` is defined to be whatever canvas context you want it to be (in the above code, this means you want something like

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

in your html).

If `theta` is in degrees, you can use `Math.cos(Math.PI * theta / 180.0)` and `Math.sin(Math.PI * theta / 180.0)` instead of `Math.cos(theta)` and `Math.sin(theta)` to get the job done...

Comment: Great thanks a lot massive help. Got this so far http://jsfiddle.net/HvLJR/1/ will convert to degrees tomorrow.

Comment: @Floris, My use case is little bit different. I have a line on canvas which is not parallel to neither x nor y axis. It is a random line anywhere in canvas. I have to draw another line with the help of given angle and length. Say one line is there (10,20) to (30,40) and then I want to create another line from (30,40) with the given angle and length. Please help.

Comment: If I follow the code snippets you provided the new line is getting created with the desired angle but the angle is creating considering the y axis not with a existing line.

Comment: @Floris, Thanks for responding on this old post :)
Can you please give the code snippet like you gave for the original question which helped me a lot. I have taken the code snippet which you mentioned in the answer section 6 years back. If you can tell me what to modify for my use case then it will a great help!

Comment: @SuryaN Sorry my attempt at showing what to do would not format correctly and I ran out of editing time so had to delete the comment. You need a 2D rotation matrix to go from relative coordinates to absolute. You will honestly learn more if you try this yourself first - google “rotate 2D vector”. Basically we have a vector of the form [r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)] now; You need to multiply that by the rotation matrix for the original vector relative to which you want to draw.

Comment: The result will look something like this (doing off the top of my head .... errors possible): r*[cos(phi)*cos(theta) -sin(phi)*sin(theta), sin(phi)*cos(theta)+cos(phi)*sin(theta)] where phi is the angle of the vector relative to which you want to dra, and theta is the angle you want between the two vectors. See if you can make that work.