# How to create an SVG Matrix without an SVG element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I have been accessing the SVGMatrix prototype to use its power for matrix transformations. These transformations are not necessarily related to any SVG element

```
var svgElement = $('svg')[0];
var svgMatrix = svgElement.createSVGMatrix()
Object.create(svgMatrix.__proto__)
```

Essentially I want to be able to create a svgMatrix as in line two without first relying on a svg element in the DOM as in line 1.

Comment: @Sirko that method creates and unknowelement not an SVG I am not sure what this means in practice but that created element will not have method createSVGMatrix

Comment: @Sirko as example try in a page with an svg a = document.createElement('svg'); then a.constructor.name

Comment: @RobertLongson do you mean root element as in body or html. if so how do I use that to access the svg namespace

Comment: Thank you I was just reading about createElementNS on MDN

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about

```
var matrix = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg").createSVGMatrix();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `new DOMMatrix()`. It's the same thing.

Even though `DOMMatrix !== SVGMatrix`,

they share the same constructor `DOMMatrix.constructor === SVGMatrix.constructor`.

`lib.dom.d.ts` also equates the two:

```
type SVGMatrix = DOMMatrix;
declare var SVGMatrix: typeof DOMMatrix;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not true. Although similar, they are not the same. Methods like SVG.getCTM/getScreenCTM will not allow DOMMatrix and throw as a result.