# Is it possible to use Proxy with native browser objects (HTMLElement, Canvas2DRenderingContext ,...)?

Tags: javascript

What I was trying to accomplish. I wanted to share a single canvas (because what I'm doing is very heavy) and so I thought I'd make a limited resource manager. You'd ask it for the resource via promise, in this case a `Canvas2DRenderingContext`. It would wrap the context in a revokable proxy. When you're finished you are required to call release which both returns the canvas to the limited resource manager so it can give it to someone else AND it revokes the proxy so the user can't accidentally use the resource again.

Except when I make a proxy of a `Canvas2DRenderingContext` it fails.

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
const proxy = new Proxy(ctx, {});

// try to change the width of the canvas via the proxy
test(() => { proxy.canvas.width = 100; });  // ERROR

// try to translate the origin of via the proxy
test(() => { proxy.translate(1, 2); });     // ERROR


function test(fn) {
  try {
    fn();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("FAILED:", e, fn);
  }
}
```

The code above generates `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` in Chrome and `TypeError: 'get canvas' called on an object that does not implement interface CanvasRenderingContext2D.` in Firefox

Is that an expected limitation of Proxy or is it a bug?

note: of course there are other solutions. I can remove the proxy and just not worry about it. I can also wrap the canvas in some JavaScript object that just exposes the functions I need and proxy that. I'm just more curious if this is supposed to work or not. [This Mozilla blog post kind of indirectly suggests it's supposed to be possbile](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-proxies-and-reflect/) since it actually mentions using a proxy with an `HTMLElement` if only to point out it would certainly fail if you called `someElement.appendChild(proxiedElement)` but given the simple code above I'd expect it's actually not possible to meanfully wrap any DOM elements or other native objects.

Below is proof that Proxies work with plain JS objects. They work with class based (as in the functions are on the prototype chain). And they don't work with native objects.

```js
const img = document.createElement('img')
const proxy = new Proxy(img, {});
console.log(proxy.src);
```

Also fails with the same error. where as they don't with JavaScript objects

```js
function testNoOpProxy(obj, msg) {
  log(msg, '------');
  const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {});
  check("get property:", () => proxy.width);
  check("set property:", () => proxy.width = 456);
  check("get property:", () => proxy.width);
  check("call fn on object:", () => proxy.getContext('2d'));
}

function check(msg, fn) {
  let success = true;
  let r;
  try {
    r = fn();
  } catch (e) {
    success = false;
  }
  log('   ', success ? "pass" : "FAIL", msg, r, fn);
}


const test = {
  width: 123,
  getContext: function() {
    return "test";
  },
};

class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.width = 123;
  }
  getContext() {
    return `Test width = ${this.width}`;
  }
}

const testInst = new Test();
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

testNoOpProxy(test, 'plain object');
testNoOpProxy(testInst, 'class object');
testNoOpProxy(canvas, 'native object');



function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

Well FWIW the solution I choose was to wrap the canvas in a small class that does the thing I was using it for. Advantage is it's easier to test (since I can pass in a mock) and I can proxy that object no problem. Still, I'd like to know

1. Why doesn't Proxy work for native object?
2. Do any of the reasons Proxy doesn't work with native objects apply to situations with JavaScript objects?
3. Is it possible to get Proxy to work with native objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that whatever you pass as a handler, accessing the target properties will be done from the proxy itself, and not from the handler. Overwriting CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.canvas to log `this` in the getter logs the Proxy instance. So even `new Proxy(ctx, ctx)` would not work as a no-op...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const handlers = {
  get: (target, key) => key in target ? target[key] : undefined,
  set: (target, key, value) => {
    if (key in target) {
      target[key] = value;
    }
    return value;
  }
};

const { revoke, proxy } = Proxy.revocable(ctx, handlers);

// elsewhere
try {
  proxy.canvas.width = 500;
} catch (e) { console.log("Access has been revoked", e); }
```

Something like that should do what you're expecting.
A revocable proxy, with handlers for get and set traps, for the context.

Just keep in mind that when an instance of `Proxy.revocable()` is revoked, any subsequent access of that proxy will throw, and thus everything now needs to use try/catch, in the case that it has, indeed, been revoked.

Just for fun, here's how you can do the exact same thing without fear of throwing (in terms of simply using the accessor; no guarantee for doing something wrong while you still have access):

```
const RevocableAccess = (item, revoked = false) => ({
  access: f => revoked ? undefined : f(item),
  revoke: () => { revoked = true; }
});

const { revoke, access: useContext } = RevocableAccess(ctx);

useContext(ctx => ctx.canvas.width = 500);
revoke();
useContext(ctx => ctx.canvas.width = 200); // never fires
```

### Edit

As pointed out in the comments below, I completely neglected to test for the method calls on the host object, which, it turns out, are all protected. This comes down to weirdness in the host objects, which get to play by their own rules.

With a proxy as above, `proxy.drawImage.apply(ctx, args)` would work just fine.
This, however, is counter-intuitive.

Cases that I'm assuming fail here, are Canvas, Image, Audio, Video, Promise (for instance based methods) and the like. I haven't conferred with the spec on this part of Proxies, and whether this is a property-descriptor thing, or a host-bindings thing, but I'm going to assume that it's the latter, if not both.

That said, you *should* be able to override it with the following change:

```
const { proxy, revoke } = Proxy.revocable(ctx, {
  get(object, key) {
    if (!(key in object)) {
      return undefined;
    }
    const value = object[key];
    return typeof value === "function"
      ? (...args) => value.apply(object, args)
      : value;
  }
});
```

Here, I am still "getting" the method off of the original object, to call it.
It just so happens that in the case of the value being a function, I call bind to return a function that maintains the `this` relationship to the original context. Proxies usually handle this common JS issue.

...this causes its own security concern; someone could cache the value out, now, and have permanent access to, say, `drawImage`, by saying
`const draw = proxy.drawImage;`...
Then again, they already had the ability to save the real render context, just by saying
`const ctx = proxy.canvas.getContext("2d");`
...so I'm assuming some level of good-faith, here.

For a more secure solution, there are other fixes, though with canvas, unless it's in-memory only, the context is ultimately going to be available to anyone who can read the DOM.

Comment: I think a complementary note about why the original code was throwing would be a + for this answer. How comes some property can't be forwarded by the no-op handler `{}`?

Comment: @Kaiido edited. You aren't going to find any benefit of a no-op handler, one way or another; there is no handler for getting. As for the other, the proxy is mimicking a protected object; without being able to act like that object (via handlers), you're going to have problems.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to this Proxy thing, and note that I am not the asker. I just notice that while your answer does indeed provide a solution for the problem, it doesn't explain the problem. I still can't see anything in your answer stating why the no-op handler OP used thrown in these cases. And while I can get a sight of what happens, I can't explain it to myself in clear words.

Comment: Also passing the `Reflect` object would be considered a "no-op" handler.

Comment: Passing `Refect` also fails on native objects so it is also **not** a no-op

Comment: This answer does not actually solve the issue. Trying to call any of the methods of the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` via the proxy all throw.

Comment: @gman you're right. I neglected to account for accessing methods of native objects. You can get around it with `.apply(ctx)`, but that's sub-optimal, for very obvious reasons. I'll edit this when I get home.

Comment: Interesting solution though if I understand it correctly it's creating a new function on every function call. Based on your answer how about this? https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/2ywoucn3/

Comment: @gman So one major concern in that regard is that you are now opening yourself up to major state mutation problems. Cache two function references (think `.bind`) and then call the first function. Which method runs? Now, if nobody on your team, or using your code, will be passing in bound methods as callbacks, that&#39;s totally valid. But if this is library code you would break a lot of people, for the sake of saving a function context. Again, if we&#39;re talking calling this hundreds of times at 60fps, I get it. At 10fps, I don’t, personally.