# Javascript Proxy gives Illegal invocation error

Tags: javascript

I cannot figured out why I got `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error when calling `getAttribute` from a Javascript proxy.

https://jsbin.com/raqafazixe/1/edit?html,js,console

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

Here's the Javascript code:

```
const a = document.querySelector('#a');
console.log(a.getAttribute('id'));
console.log(new Proxy(a, {}).getAttribute('id'));
```

And here's the output:

```
a
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075255/proxy-htmlelement and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535551/is-it-possible-to-use-proxy-with-native-browser-objects-htmlelement-canvas2dre Your Proxy is not an Element and can't call its target's getAttribute on its behalf.

Comment: Using the [solution there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48536014/3702797): https://jsfiddle.net/4okdtzp9/

Comment: Similar using `bind(target)` https://jsfiddle.net/eo5f6hry/1/

Comment: Thank you so much!